# Upgrading Jackson from 2.0.4 to 2.7.1

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to upgrade my project to use a newer version of Jackson and have run into a snag with custom Serializers and Deserializers.

On the following deserializer I am getting a **constructor** issue - I am not sure what type I should be passing in.  The constructor I am using is no longer available. Below is the current class:

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdKeyDeserializer;

public class SifMapKeyDeserializer extends StdKeyDeserializer {

```
protected SifMapKeyDeserializer(Class<?> cls) {
    super(cls); //IT COMPLAINS.  It needs a type, not sure what type?
}

@Override
protected Object _parse(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper jacksonMapper = ObjectMapperFactory.getObjectMapper();
    JsonNode element =  jacksonMapper.readTree(key);

    String fullClassName = element.path(JacksonExtConstants.JAVA_CLASS_NAME_KEY).asText();
    String nodeText = element.toString();
    Object result = null;
    try {
        result = jacksonMapper.readValue(nodeText, Class.forName(fullClassName));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

**EDIT** I found this to solve the issue above.

```
public SifMapKeyDeserializer(Class<?> cls) {
    super(StdKeyDeserializer.TYPE_CLASS, cls);
}
```

The deserializer is listed below.  I have an issue with the contruction of the **AnnotatedMethod** and the **SimpleBeanPropertyDefinition** - I am not sure how to correct these issues.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationMap;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BeanPropertyDefinition;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.SimpleBeanPropertyDefinition;


/**
 * This custom bean serializer is to allow us add/delete any properties.
 * For example for each deserialized bean we are currently adding its fully 
 * qualified class name.
 *
 */
public class SifBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
    public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config,
            BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {

            Class cc = beanDesc.getType().getRawClass();      
            Method m;
            try {
                m = cc.getMethod("getClass", null);
                AnnotatedMethod am = new AnnotatedMethod(m, _emptyAnnotationMap(), null);
                BeanPropertyDefinition propDef = new SimpleBeanPropertyDefinition(am, JacksonExtConstants.JAVA_CLASS_NAME_KEY);
                BeanPropertyWriter beanPropWriter = new BeanPropertyWriter(propDef,
                            am, null,
                            SimpleType.constructUnsafe(Class.class),
                            null, null, SimpleType.constructUnsafe(Class.class),
                            true, null);

                beanProperties.add(beanPropWriter);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }      
        return beanProperties;
    }


    private AnnotationMap _emptyAnnotationMap() {
        return new AnnotationMap();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it like this::

```
public class SifBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config,
        BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {

        Class cc = beanDesc.getType().getRawClass();      
        Method m;
        try {
            m = cc.getMethod("getClass", null);
            TypeResolutionContext.Basic tb = new TypeResolutionContext.Basic(TypeFactory.defaultInstance(), TypeBindings.emptyBindings());
            AnnotatedMethod am = new AnnotatedMethod(tb, m, _emptyAnnotationMap(), null);
            BeanPropertyDefinition propDef = SimpleBeanPropertyDefinition.construct(config, am, JacksonExtConstants.JAVA_CLASS_NAME_KEY);
            BeanPropertyWriter beanPropWriter = new BeanPropertyWriter(propDef,
                        am, null,
                        SimpleType.constructUnsafe(Class.class),
                        null, null, SimpleType.constructUnsafe(Class.class),
                        true, null);

            beanProperties.add(beanPropWriter);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      
    return beanProperties;
}


private AnnotationMap _emptyAnnotationMap() {
    return new AnnotationMap();
}
```

}